# javascript / d3 - passing parameters to a function

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using a javascript library called d3 in order to perform some animations on an object. At the end of each animation I want to call a function which is passed data from the object which called the animation, but it's not working. How do I accomplish this? Here's my code:

```
function selectArcs() {
    d3.selectAll("g.arc > path")
        .each(arcTween)
}


function arcTween(d,i){
    console.log(i); //registers as 0, then 1

    d3.select(this)
        .transition().duration(1000)
        .attrTween("d", tweenArc({ init : d.value }))
        .each("end",function(i){ console.log(i); }); //registers as 0, then 0 - should be 0, then 1
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `function(i){ console.log(i); }` You're calling the parameter `i` but it's actually what would commonly be called `d`!

Try replacing it with `function(dOrWhatever){ console.log(i); }` (this should get the `i` variable from `function arcTween(d,i)`)