# How to bring variables into the scope of the .each method in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm working with d3 and would like to pass some variables into the scope of a function run by a selection.each() call. I'm declaring the variables `e` and `D` within an exterior function, and then within that function, after declaring my variables, running an anaonymous function on everything of the class `.points`. My problem is that I don't seem to be able to get `D` and `e` into the scope of the inner function without making them global variables. Is there a simple way of passing these into the inner function?

```
function endSelection(d){
    var e = selector.extent();
    var D = d;

    mainSVG.selectAll(".points")
        .each(function(d){
            if(d[D.x] >= e[0][0]){
                d3.select(this).call(addClass,["foo"])
                d3.select(this).call(removeClass,["bar"])
            } else {
                d3.select(this).call(addClass,["bar"])
                d3.select(this).call(removeClass,["foo"])
            };
        });
}
```

Comment: I think this is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898726/javascript-d3-passing-parameters-to-a-function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to list "d" in the formal parameters for that anonymous function.

```
mainSVG.selectAll(".points")
    .each(function(){
        if(d[D.x] >= e[0][0]){
```

Variables declared in outer scopes are **always** available in inner scopes unless they're "shadowed" by a more-inner declaration of the same identifier. That's what's happening in your code.

You don't need "D" at all; just reference "d".  Now, if the d3 code passes something useful to the function used as the `.each()` iterator, then declare it, but give it a name different from "d":

```
mainSVG.selectAll(".points")
    .each(function(not_d){
        if(not_d[d.x] >= e[0][0]){
```

Comment: I think the d argument in the inner function is meant to be different than that in the outer function - .each will pass in the current item's datum for each call. So the two d's might be intentionally different (though personally I'd name them differently).

Comment: @nrabinowitz yes I updated the answer; I'm sure you're right.